# Android seek bar with skinny background

Tags: android, android-widget

I am creating a custom style for a seek bar using xml:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="#00FF00" />
            <corners android:radius="0dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip>
            <shape>
                <solid android:color="#FF0000" />
                <corners android:radius="0dp" />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>
</layer-list>

<style name="Widget.MySeekBar" parent="android:Widget.SeekBar">
    <item name="android:indeterminateOnly">false</item>
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/seek_bar_progress</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">3dp</item>
    <item name="android:maxHeight">3dp</item>
    <item name="android:thumb">@drawable/image_seek_bar_thumb</item>
    <item name="android:thumbOffset">8dp</item>
    <item name="android:focusable">true</item>
</style>
```

I want the background to be thinner than the progress similar to the standard jelly bean style seek bars. Is there any way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have used this in xml:

```
   <SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekID"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayoutComponentTopRow"
    android:layout_marginTop="1px"
    android:background="@drawable/slide_bar"
    android:progress="0"
    android:secondaryProgress="0"
    android:thumb="@drawable/bt_slider" />
```

It sets the background and the thumbnail too.
I hope it helps!